# Why are function expressions returning non-reference types considered to be prvalues and not xvalues?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

`§ 3.10.1.5` from the standard defines `prvalue` expressions as:

> — A prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an rvalue that is not an xvalue. [ Example: The result of calling a function
>   whose return type is not a reference is a prvalue. The value of a literal such as 12, 7.3e5, or true is
>   also a prvalue. — end example ]

Thus the function `foo()` is a `prvalue` expression:

```
class Foo {}; 
Foo foo() { return Foo{}; }
```

To initialize a `lvalue reference to a non-volatile const type` / `rvalue reference` the initializer expression has to be ( `§ 5.2.1.1` ) :

> [...] an xvalue (but not a bit-field), class prvalue, array prvalue or function lvalue and “cv1 T1”
>   is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2”, or [...]

Thus,

```
Foo &&rrFoo_ = foo();
```

is valid code where `rrFoo_` binds to a temporary object extending the lifetime of the object (`§12.2`):

> Temporaries of class type are created in various contexts: binding a reference to a prvalue (8.5.3), returning
>   a prvalue (6.6.3), a conversion that creates a prvalue (4.1, 5.2.9, 5.2.11, 5.4), throwing an exception (15.1),
>   and in some initializations (8.5).

As stated above and neglecting RVO, the following initialization of an object of type `Foo` will copy move construct a temporary from default constructed object. The temporary object which will then be used to copy move construct the final object named `obj_foo` :

```
Foo obj_foo{ foo() };
```

So in both cases we either *steal* from or even *extend the lifetime* of the temporary object, which would otherwise be destroyed.

`§3.10.1.2` defines xvalues as:

> An xvalue (an “eXpiring” value) also refers to an object, usually near the end of its lifetime (so that its
>   resources may be moved, for example). [...]

I cannot think of any case where a temporary object isn't created. So my question is, why are function expressions like `foo()` are considered to be `prvalue` expression even thought they have *at least* similar properties as `xvalues` ?

Comment: You can write user-defined lvalue and xvalue expressions, too: `int & f();`, `int && g();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `int f1()` and `int && f2()`, it's intended that `decltype(f1())` is `int`, and `decltype(f2())` is `int &&`. The way this is made to work is by specifying that `f1()` is a prvalue and `f2()` is an xvalue. `decltype` then looks at whether the given expression is a prvalue, xvalue or lvalue. If `f1()` and `f2()` were both xvalues, that same distinction would still need to be made some other way.