# In C++17, temporary objects are considered xvalues rather than prvalues, correct?

Tags: c++, xvalue, prvalue

Firstly, I understand that xvalues and prvalues are value categories of expressions and not directly related to temporary objects. However, expressions are flexible and a temporary object can be viewed as an expression. For instance:

```cpp
string("hello") + string(" world");
```

The result of the operation is a temporary object, but the entire operation can be viewed as an expression, and the value category of this expression is prvalue.

Now, let me elaborate on my question. There might be similar questions already, but I assure you the content of my question is unique. The title might be brief and possibly repetitive, but it’s for the sake of brevity.

Here’s my question:

In C++17, there’s a concept called “temporary materialization”. For example:

```cpp
struct A{
    int m{10};
};
int x = A().m;
```

In this case, `A()` would generate a temporary object before C++17, but in C++17, it represents an Initializer, and no temporary object is generated. However, since it references the data member `A::m`, a temporary object must be generated. So, it’s considered that an implicit conversion from prvalue to xvalue has occurred. That is, `A()` originally wouldn’t generate a temporary object and is a prvalue, but here it needs a temporary object, so `A()` is implicitly converted from Initializer to temporary object, and temporary objects belong to xvalue in C++17, so what happened is an implicit conversion from prvalue to xvalue.

If the above viewpoint holds, then how would you explain the following scenario?

```cpp
struct A(){
    A(){cout << "A::A()" << endl;}
    A(const A&) { cout << "A::A(const A&)" << endl;}
    A(A&&) noexcept { cout << "A::A(A&&)" << endl;}
    ~A() { cout << "A::~A()" << endl;}

    // Note the return type of this function, it's not a lvalue reference, but an object type
    A operator=(const A& that){
        cout << "A::operator=(const A&)" << endl;
        if(this != &that){
            // Perform assignment operation
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a1;
    A a2;
    A a3;
    a1 = a2 = a3;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```bash
A::A()
A::A()
A::A()
A::operator=(const A&)
A::A(const A&)
A::operator=(const A&)
A::A(const A&)
A::~A()
A::~A()
A::~A()
A::~A()
A::~A()
```

From the output, it’s clear that a temporary object must have been generated at `a2=a3`. The `operator=` inside `(*this)` performs a copy construction, constructing a temporary object, and then this temporary object is assigned to `a1`. Let’s refer to this temporary object as `temp`. Then, `a1=temp` also results in a temporary object, because the copy constructor is called for the second time.

Since the return value of `operator=` here is a temporary object, it should be an xvalue, not a prvalue. However, if I test it using `decltype((expr))`, the test result is prvalue, as follows:

```cpp
namespace detail
{
template <class T> struct value_category
{
    static constexpr char const *value = "prvalue";
};
template <class T> struct value_category<T &>
{
    static constexpr char const *value = "lvalue";
};
template <class T> struct value_category<T &&>
{
    static constexpr char const *value = "xvalue";
};
} // namespace detail
#define PRINT_VALUE_CAT(expr)                                                                                          \
    std::cout << #expr << " is a " << ::detail::value_category<decltype((expr))>::value << '\n'

PRINT_VALUE_CAT(a1=a2=a3);      // The print result is a1=a2=a3 is a prvalue
```

Why has the temporary object become a prvalue again? Wasn’t it said that temporary objects are xvalues? I would appreciate any insights or explanations on this matter. Thank you!

Comment: It hasn't become a prvalue again. The expression `a1=a2=a3` has the value category of prvalue from the start because you're returning **by value** and a function call like `f()` where `f` returns by value is a prvalue. See dupe: [Why are function expressions returning non-reference types considered to be prvalues and not xvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043414/why-are-function-expressions-returning-non-reference-types-considered-to-be-prva)

Comment: In `a1=a2=a3`, `a2=a3` is originally a prvalue but materializes to become a xvalue due to the call of `operator=` on `a1`, but that has nothing to do with the value category of the whole expression `a1=a2=a3`. Value categories cannot persist across function calls. The value category of a function call expression is solely determined by the signature of the function and nothing else. `a1=a2=a3` is a brand new prvalue so there is no "temporary object becomes prvalue again" happening here. The temperory is consumed by the function and that's all there is to it.